# How to write if condition in gurobi 9.5?

Tags: gurobi

Any example for using if statement in gurobi 9.5 ?

its my first time to use gurobi. I am trying to implement the following code via if statement however i keep getting error or infeasible model.

m.addConstrs(p2g[t]==0  for t in range(A) if pv_generation[t]<=load[t] pfor t in range(A) )

m.addConstrs(p2g[t]==p2g[t]  for t in range(A) if pv_generation[t]>load[t] for t in range(A))

I've checked the gurobi documentation but it doesn't provide any clear example

Comment: [This answer in the Gurobi forum](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360078062211-Conditional-statement-in-Gurobi) may help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried indicator constraint and got this error    (unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'NoneType' and 'float')  . I guess the indicator constraint doesn't work with multi-constraint (m.addConstrs), but only works with (m.addConstr)

Comment: I suggest asking at the Gurobi forums. They are usually very responsive.